# What's the deal with John From Cincinnati?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-from-cincinnati

HBO had a series in 2007 called John From Cincinnati. It was weird and surreal. The main character (John) seemed to know nothing at the start, like a baby, and just mimicked people. He also had supernatural abilities.

Does anyone know John's backstory? Where did he come from? Was he an angel? What was the thrust of the series going to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I could find of particular usefulness to this question was a [local article on patch.com](http://imperialbeach.patch.com/groups/opinion/p/john-from-cincinnati-imperial-beach), which contains this blurb regarding an interview with David Milch (the series co-creator):

> “The idea [behind John from Cincinnati is] that the universe is a
>   solid system but [also] a series of waves,” he said. “And that man is
>   not an individual creature, but that his essence is carried from
>   seeming individual to seeming individual [and becomes] available to
>   surfers if they aren't loaded and selfish or if they don't become
>   addicted to the behavior of surfing itself."

He also states that the rush for production was counter-productive and he didn't have time to fully develop the story or characters.

Additionally, [this review](http://www.avclub.com/article/wildly-enigmatic-case-file-7-ijohn-from-cincinnati-67835) of the show gets very indepth, and states the show is about

> "forsaking the rational in favor of the unknowable. John From
>   Cincinnati at times feels more like a waking dream or a visual poem
>   than a conventional TV series."

Comment: Thanks! That idea is TRIPPY! I wish that series had continued, since it's such an interesting concept!! It did start losing me, though, because the idea wasn't really spelled out.

Comment: And I'd still like to know where John came from. He is a "tabla rasa" (blank slate) at the beginning, even though he's a full-grown adult.

Comment: My guess is Cincinnatti?  :o)  I don't think they had enough time to really develop all of that backstory.

Comment: HAHAHA! I set myself up for that one! Since I was a writer myself for years, I know that the series creator had a whole backstory that would have unfolded over the course of the series if HBO had kept the series going.